# Serilog does not work after await is called

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I have the following code

```
    public async Task<bool> Execute()
    {

        Log.Information($"Importing CSV File: '{FilePath}' to table '{TableName}' Connection String: {ConnectionString}");

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {

            Log.Information("Connection opening");
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            Log.Information("Connection opened");
            using (var tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {

                await TruncateExistingData(conn, tran);


                await ImportData(conn, tran);

                tran.Commit();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

What is unusual is that `Log.Information("Connection opening");` this actually works and logs as it should but the statement `Log.Information("Connection opened");` does not log even though the connection was opened successfully.

I have also updated my code so that the Async library is included, here is the setup

```
  Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .WriteTo.Async(x=>x.File(logFilePath))                       
                    .WriteTo.Async(x=>x.Console())                        
                    .CreateLogger();
```

EDIT:
Seems like calling `Log.CloseAndFlush()` is causing the issue, even if i have it at the end of my `main()` method

Comment: It looks like you are not waiting the async operations to complete, on your Main method, before calling ‘Log.CloseAndFlush()’. Can you post how your Main method looks like?

Comment: Not enough context. Please add your `main()`.